# Multiple threads use the same SimpleDateFormat without ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I am trying to understand the need of using `ThreadLocal`. Lot of people mention `ThreadLocal` should be used to provide a Per-Thread `SimpleDateFormat`, but they do not mention how will a mangled `SimpleDateFormat` will be seen if `ThreadLocal` is not used. I try the following code, seems it is just fine, I don't see a mangled `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ThreadLocalTest {
  private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  private static final Date TODAY = new Date();
  private static final String expected = "07/09/2016";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            String real = dateFormat.format(TODAY);
            if (!real.equals(expected)) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Mangled SimpleDateFormat");
            }
          }
        }
      }).start();
    }
  }
}
```

How can I produce a exception like `NumberFormatException` because I don't use a `ThreadLocal` ?

Comment: you ran it just for 1000 times and use `println`, which is a synchronized method. Instead run it forever, don't print anything, and throw an exception when you get a string different from the expected one.

Comment: Seems if I use `parse` method I would be able to see an exception easily.

Answer (score 3):

The crucial point is: the SimpleDateFormat implementation is **not** thread safe.

That doesn't mean that it will throw an exception. 
It is **worse**: maybe, occasionally the shared formatter will simply give you wrong output!

You know, if "multi-threading issues" would nicely throw exceptions at you ... people would be much less afraid of them. Because we would have a direct hint that something went wrong.

Instead, things go wrong - and **unnoticed**.

Suggestion: enhance your test to

1. always format the **same** Date object
2. check that the **result** of formatting **that** Date is as expected (for example by comparing it against the result of an initial, first formatting operation)

And of course: only print mismatches, so that notice when they happen. Or better: throw your own exception on mismatch!

EDIT: turns out that the "better" way to enforce inconsistencies is to not use *formatting* but *parsing*!

Finally, to address another comment: of course, inconsistencies can only occur for objects that are **shared** between multiple threads. When each thread has its **own** format object, than there is no sharing; thus no problem.

Comment: Even I updated the my test(See the edited in my question) I could not see an exception. It would be good if I can see an exception because I am not using a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: I dont know what else to say. It doesn't matter what you think "would be good". The java language and the JVM do what they; no matter what we think about it. As said: when multiple threads **corrupt** a shared object, then there is no exception. You just get data corruption. That is the whole point that makes **sharing** state between threads **difficult**. And you or me not liking that won't change that.

Comment: Thanks. Have one more question. What the difference if I just simple new a `SimpleDateFormat` when I new a `Thread` compared with using a `ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just run these code, you will get "java.lang.NumberFormatException". If not occur, run a few more times

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class ThreadLocalDemo1 implements Runnable {
private static final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadLocalDemo1 td = new ThreadLocalDemo1();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(td, "Thread-1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(td, "Thread-2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        System.out.println("Thread run execution started for " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("Date formatter pattern is  " + simpleDateFormat.toPattern());

        try {
            System.out.println("Formatted date is " + simpleDateFormat.parse("2013-05-24 06:02:20"));
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("=========================================================");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Date formats are not thread safe.

I think if you format the same day you can't reproduce, you should use 2 different dates or format also second and dates that have different seconds etc. Date format uses a Calendar under the hood on which it sets the date. If the first thread sets a date and start formatting the string and another thread with a different date comes and sets it on the same calendar, you will get wrong output.

Following code produces an exception/error:

```
    final Date today = new Date();
    String expectedToday = dateFormat.format(today);

    Date yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
    String expectedYesterday = dateFormat.format(yesterday);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    String format = dateFormat.format(today);
                    if (!expectedToday.equals(format)) {
                        System.out.println("error: " + format + " " + expectedToday);//Throw exception if you want
                    }

                    format = dateFormat.format(yesterday);
                    if (!expectedYesterday.equals(format)) {
                        System.out.println("error: " + format + " " + expectedYesterday);//Throw exception if you want
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe is that it has an internal `calendar` field, which holds a `Calendar` object.  Pretty much the first thing that `SimpleDateFormat` does before actually formatting the date is call `this.calendar.setTime(theDateYouPassedIn)`, no synchronization or locks.  I'm not sure if this is the only way, but it should be fairly straightforward to inspect the code.

So, one way to get `SimpleDateFormat` to fail is to use dates that will produce differing output in different threads.  Here is an example:

```
public class NotThreadSafe
{
  private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date dref = new Date();

    // Dates for yesterday and tomorrow
    Date[] ds = new Date[] {
        new Date(dref.getTime() - (24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L)),
        new Date(dref.getTime() + (24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L))
    };
    String[] refs = new String[ds.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.length; ++i) {
      // How the corresponding ds[i] should be formatted
      refs[i] = dateFormat.format(ds[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      // Every even numbered thread uses ds[0] and refs[0],
      // odd numbered threads use ds[1] and refs[1].
      int index = (i % 2);
      final Date d = ds[index];
      final String ref = refs[index];
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          while (true) {
            String s = dateFormat.format(d);
            if (!ref.equals(s)) {
              throw new IllegalStateException("Expected: " + ref + ", got: " + s);
            }
          }
        }
      }).start();
    }
  }
}
```

As the comments show, every even numbered thread will format yesterday's date, and odd numbered threads will use tomorrows date.

If you run this, threads will pretty much immediately start committing suicide by throwing exceptions until such time as you have only a handful left, likely all formatting the same date.